# Problem in Updating ContentVersion

Tags: contentversion, issue

I am trying to update contentVersion multiple times in code in same transaction. However unlike salesforce records (eg. Account) , contentVersion is holding only first updated value and only those changes are made to file. Rest all changes are getting discarded. Is this is the expected behaviour ?
Please refer to code snippet below

```
String publicationId = [SELECT LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument where id = '0690I00000I9NZA' limit 1].LatestPublishedVersionId;
ContentVersion cv1 = [select versionData from contentVersion where id =: publicationId  limit 1];
system.debug('===initial==='+cv1.versiondata.toString());
cv1.versionData = blob.valueof('test');
update cv1;
system.debug('==after==1st change='+cv1.versiondata.toString());

ContentVersion cv2 = [select versionData from contentVersion where contentDocumentId = '0690I00000I9NZA' limit 1];
cv2.versionData = blob.valueof('test1');
update cv2;
system.debug('==after==2nd change='+cv2.versiondata.toString());

String publicationId1 = [SELECT LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument where id = '0690I00000I9NZA' limit 1].LatestPublishedVersionId;
ContentVersion cv4 = [select versionData from contentVersion where id =: publicationId  limit 1];
system.debug('===final==='+cv4.versiondata.toString());
```

Output

```
*******debug result******************************************* 
20:19:21.25 (69355295)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|===initial===testing
20:19:21.25 (192058770)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|==after==1st change=test
20:19:21.25 (247430322)|USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|==after==2nd change=test1
20:19:21.25 (300835207)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|===final===test
```

Expected is test1 not test

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a typo in your `WHERE` clause:

```
String publicationId1 = [SELECT LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument where id = '0690I00000I9NZA' limit 1].LatestPublishedVersionId;
ContentVersion cv4 = [select versionData from contentVersion 
     where id =: publicationId  limit 1];  // You are referencing publicationId, not publicationId1
```

You were referencing the original CV which had a value of `test`